# Django "default=timezone.now()" saves records using the "old" time of when the Django server starts

Tags: python, django, django-models, timestamp, django-timezone

This issue has been occurring on and off for a few weeks now, and it's unlike any that has come up with my project.

Two of the models that are used have a timestamp field, which is by default set to `timezone.now()`.

This is the sequence that raises error flags:

---

- Model one is created at time 7:30 PM
- Model two is created at time 10:00 PM, but in the 
     MySQL database it's stored as 7:30 PM!

Every model that is created 
    has its time stamp saved under 7:30 PM, not the actual time, until a certain
    duration passes. Then a new time is set and all the following models
    have that new time... Bizzare

---

Some extra details which may help in discovering the issue:

I have a bunch of methods that I use to strip my timezones of their `tzinfo`'s and replace them with UTC.

This is because I'm doing a `timezone.now() - creationTime` calculation to create a: "model was posted this long ago" feature
in the project. However, this really should not be the cause of the problem.

I don't think using `datetime.datetime.now()` will make any difference either.

Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: I bet the problem "is fixed" for the first record *after* the server process restarts (and perhaps only/all new records inserted the same minute of the server restart). Please show the code that uses/sets/establishes this default value. I suspect that it is only evaluated *once* (when the first record is created) and not updated for subsequent records.

Comment: Your prediction is correct! What makes you think this and why would it be happening?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just ran into this last week for a field that had `default=date.today()`. If you remove the parentheses (in this case, try `default=timezone.now`) then you're passing a callable to the model and it will be called each time a new instance is saved. With the parentheses, it's only being called once when `models.py` loads.

Comment: This is very cool, thanks for the response. The function pass is rather misleading because since starting out with django as an amateaur, every single guide that I've read and the books even all have had datetime.datetime.now() or timezone.now() set as default for timestamps, it's just become something i've done automatically for all my timestamps!

Comment: I suppose doing it wrong this way would appear to work if you only deployed your Django apps with old-fashioned CGI; and of course you have to test over a period of hours or days to notice these timestamps not updating... But if this is widespread advice it doesn't give me confidence in those authors' testing. :-/

Comment: I'm not sure what examples would ever suggest calling `datetime.now()`. By the time the field function receives that argument, it's just a datetime object.

Comment: what if i am calling timezone.now() in views.py file to use in queryset

Answer (score 25):

Just set the parameter `auto_now_add` like this.

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Update:

Please don't use `auto_now_add`. It is not the recommended way, instead do this:

```
from django.utils import timezone

timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: This is no longer a preferred method of accomplishing this. [Deprecated](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22995)

Comment: what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You should set [timezone.now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) without `()` to [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) as [a default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#default) as shown below. *Don't set `timezone.now()` with `()` because the default date and time become when the Django server starts (Unchanged) and don't set [datetime.now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) because [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc) is not saved correctly in database when [TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_ZONE) which is default in `settings.py`:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
# Don't set "timezone.now()" and "datetime.now" ↓ 
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```