# Django querying on range of days with timezone.now and __range broken?

Tags: python, django, django-timezone

I am running Django 1.4.3 and Python 2.7, with a PostgreSQL database (9.2.2). I have a model with a "last_view" field that is a timestamp of when a record is last viewed by a user. On my front page I want to display the ten most viewed items within the last week, so in my ListView I tried using this for my queryset:

```
startdate = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
enddate = timezone.now()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=Tag.objects.filter(last_view__range=([startdate, enddate])).order_by('-views')[:10],
            context_object_name='most_viewed_list',
            template_name='tags/index.html'),
        name='index'),
```

This works when I first load the page. If I click any of the records and "view" them, the last_view attribute is updated in the database--but if I then reload the page, this item disappears from the "Recently Viewed" list (formed by the queryset described above).

I thought the problem was related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225890/django-default-timezone-now-saves-records-using-old-time), where it seems like the "enddate" of timezone.now() is limited by when I start my server process. So when I click on a link after the server is running, the "current time" is in the future compared to "now()" and outside of the range (that is why the record I click disappears on a page reload). However, if I change things to just **now** as in the post mentioned above, I get an error on page load:

```
startdate = timezone.now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
enddate = timezone.now
```

unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'datetime.timedelta'

So I cannot create my startdate variable. I can get this to work by changing my queryset from _range to _gte, but it seems like that will break over time if **now()** is really timestamped to when the server process starts instead of "current time."

```
queryset=Tag.objects.filter(last_view__gte=(timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).order_by('-views')[:10]
```

The [Django Tutorial on testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial05/) does show the use of **now** in making queries over dates, however they do not show how to subtract days from **now** or use it with timedelta or a date range...

Can someone please explain how to take a time difference from the actual, current time, i.e. using **now** instead of **now()**? I would also like to better understand the limitations of using **now()** versus **now**. I cannot find great documentation on this, since all examples I can find with timedelta() refer to timezone.now() or datetime.now(), which works (just not the way I want it to).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subclass `ListView` and override the `get_queryset` method. By calculating the `startdate` and `enddate` inside the `get_queryset` method, `timezone.now()` will be the time when the request was made, not when the `urls.py` was initially loaded.

```
class TagListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        startdate = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        enddate = timezone.now()
        return Tag.objects.filter(last_view__range=[startdate, enddate]).order_by('-views')[:10]
    context_object_name='most_viewed_list'
    template_name='tags/index.html'

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TagListView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise response! That fixed it--I didn't realize that urls.py was only loaded once...